# My program is not saving numbers correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, database

When I enter decimal numbers from textboxes(txtMaterialUnitPrice,txtMaterialUnitPrice) like 4,5 and 6,5 the total price should come 29,25 but it comes 29. Here is my code.

```
private void btnSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        salesTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        materialPrice = Decimal.Parse(txtMaterialUnitPrice.Text);
        purchasedWeight = Decimal.Parse(txtMaterialUnitPrice.Text);
        totalPrice = materialPrice * purchasedWeight;

        curSales = Sales.Insert(customerID, customerNameSurname, customerPlate, materialID, materialType, materialPrice, purchasedWeight, totalPrice, salesTime, txtExplanation.Text);

        LoadAll();
    }
```

And this is the inserting part.

```
 public static Sales Insert(int cID, String cNameSurname, String cPlate, int mID, String mName, Decimal mPrice, Decimal pWeight, Decimal totalPrice, String dt, String explanation)
    {
        String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO sales(CustomerID,CustomerNameSurname,CustomerPlate,MaterialID,MaterialType,MaterialPrice,PurchasedWeight,TotalPrice,SalesDate,Explanation) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}' , '{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}')", cID, cNameSurname, cPlate, mID, mName, mPrice, pWeight, cleanAmount, dt, explanation);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DB.dbConn);

        DB.dbConn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int id = (int)cmd.LastInsertedId;

        Sales sale = new Sales(id, cID, cNameSurname, cPlate, mID, mName, mPrice, pWeight, totalPrice, dt, explanation);

        DB.dbConn.Close();

        return sale;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation/formatting. Use parameters instead

Comment: Probably because 29,25 would be seen as 2 values.. 29 and 25.  Let alone the concept of sql injection which is also relevant to your code

Comment: `materialPrice = Decimal.Parse(txtMaterialUnitPrice.Text);
        purchasedWeight = Decimal.Parse(txtMaterialUnitPrice.Text);` Seems like same text boxes. Is that the problem.?

Comment: As @CamiloTerevinto said, use parameters to pass the actual objects instead of string representations that may not be in the expected format for the database. Not to mention, since there are strings in there, [to avoid Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: What is "cleanAmount" ? You are inserting that value for TotalPrice column.

Comment: I was trying something it should be totalPrice of course. That is not the problem @Rainman

Comment: @DhavalR to solve the problem I was trying to do something, another textbox should be txtPurchasedWeight of course

Comment: Are you giving comma separated values to both text boxes?

Comment: Yes of course @DhavalR

Comment: So basically you want to add multiple sales entries at once..! For that use `Split` function to separate values for both textboxes. And iterate through the values.

Comment: no, I am trying to multiply materialunitprice, purchasedweight and keep them in a seperate variable which TotalPrice @DhavalR

Comment: @ersnbck - I meant are there two sales entries. one is unitPrice = 4 and weight = 6 (total = 24) and the other is unitPrice = 5 and weight = 5 (total = 25). These two entries are different.?

Comment: No the 6,5 means 6.5 this is decimal number. I want to multply 6.5 and 4.5 and get 29.25. But it saves database 29 now is it ok ?@DhavalR

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reason on that
1. Your table column 'TotalPrice' is INT type instead of DECIMAL
or
2. Your 'Sales' object class property 'TotalPrice' is  Integer or something other than not to store decimal points.

Comment: sorry but none of them is correct. Because my column is DECIMAL(10,2) type and also my property 'TotalPrice' is Decimal as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your solution is the "," sign. The comma in C# the decimal value you use the "." sign that is why it combines it

//Example
//This will work

decimal test = 7.5;

//This will not work

decimal test = 7,5;

Change the decimal pointer symbol

Comment: I have tried already this one. It changes this number and takes as 75. @user1407955

Comment: remember the syntax of parse: Decimal.TryParse(value, out number) the value you are converting and the one you are converting to in the out parameter.