# I am trapped with decimal and my sql

Tags: c#, mysql, database

For ex: When I enter decimal numbers from textboxes(txtMaterialUnitPrice,txtPurchasedWeight) like 4.5 and 6.5 the totalprice should come 29.25 but it comes 29. Here is my code.

```
 salesTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 materialPrice = decimal.Parse(txtMaterialUnitPrice.Text);
 purchasedWeight = decimal.Parse(txtPurchasedWeight.Text);
 totalPrice = materialPrice * purchasedWeight;

 curSales = Sales.Insert(customerID, customerNameSurname, customerPlate, materialID, 
 materialType, materialPrice, purchasedWeight, totalPrice, salesTime, txtExplanation.Text);
```

And this is the inserting part.

```
 public static Sales Insert(int cID, String cNameSurname, String cPlate, int mID, String mName, Decimal mPrice, Decimal pWeight, Decimal totalPrice, String dt, String explanation)
 {
    String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO sales(CustomerID,CustomerNameSurname,CustomerPlate,MaterialID,MaterialType,MaterialPrice,PurchasedWeight,TotalPrice,SalesDate,Explanation) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}' , '{2}', '{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}')", cID, cNameSurname, cPlate, mID, mName, mPrice, pWeight, totalPrice, dt, explanation);

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DB.dbConn);

    DB.dbConn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int id = (int)cmd.LastInsertedId;

    Sales sale = new Sales(id, cID, cNameSurname, cPlate, mID, mName, mPrice, pWeight, totalPrice, dt, explanation);

    DB.dbConn.Close();

    return sale;
  }
```

[Sales Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiiYP.jpg)

Comment: what is totalPrice declared as? decimal?
Have you checked that materialPrice and purchasedWeight are correctly parsed as decimals?

Comment: He has it in the very missable `Sales Table` link. It's `decimal(10,2)`.

Comment: @Shelby115 Not really.. That is a table definition, the variable could be int..

Comment: @Zaphod Ah, I see. I just came to that realization myself.

Comment: the variable is not int it is decimal. I have debugged many times the the totalPrice keeps the correct value but after inserting the result is like this @Shelby115

Comment: Yes they correctly parsed @Zaphod

Comment: Is the value in the returned sales object correct? Is the value in the table wrong?

Comment: No until insert function, everthing is correct but after that the value is not same.@Zaphod

Comment: I try to figure out where you loose the decimal digits. As I understand you now, the value is wrong in the database, right?  But is the value in the sales object returned wrong as well?
Also.. Have you set precision on the table?

Comment: Yes, the value is wrong both in database and the object as well@Zaphod

Comment: What does the `query` show if you print that? The correct value or the incorrect? Also - could it be a comma/period issue (globalization format?)

Comment: I'll rewrite a bit of code for you to test.. give me a few minutes..

Comment: Looks like the same question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076855/my-program-is-not-saving-numbers-correctly#comment83129209_48076855 (Same user?)

Comment: @DhavalR probably the same assignement ;-)

Comment: @komtan2 First, change the query to:
String query = "INSERT INTO sales(CustomerID,CustomerNameSurname,CustomerPlate,MaterialID,MaterialType,MaterialPrice,PurchasedWeight,TotalPrice,SalesDate,Explanation) VALUES (@CustomerID,@CustomerNameSurname,@CustomerPlate,@MaterialID,@MaterialType,@MaterialPrice,@PurchasedWeight,@TotalPrice,@SalesDate,@Explanation)";

Comment: then add:
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DB.dbConn);
//Add the parameters
//(This is to prevent sql injection attacks)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = cID;
   //Add all the missing ones
   //For the decimal value experiment with varchar as type if decimal doesn't work,

Comment: And before you try that.. Please try to use , as a decimal delimiter instead of . ie 4,5 and 6,5 - does that make a difference?

Comment: didn't work unfortunately @Zaphod. When I try to multiply 4.5 and 6.5 changes the number and it makes 45 and 65 gives 2925

Comment: Where is the local variable `totalPrice` declared? Not the _parameter_ to the `Insert` method.

Comment: @komtan2 It didn't work to rewrite to use sql parameters? You tried with different versions for the totalprice parameter?